# Windows 10 ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when enabling SSL

Tags: windows-10, iis-express

My office just gave me a new machine with Windows 10 and both VS2013 and VS2015 installed.  I transferred an existing VS2013 project to the machine, but when I attempt to run, I get a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error in Chrome. There doesn't appear to be a Repair IIS Express application in Win10. I considered uninstalling IIS Express 10 and install 8, but I'd need to get permission for that and it wouldn't be an easy sell. What else can I look at?

Comment: Without even knowing what is the cause of the issue, I don't think IIS 8 Express can help you out. Try to use a browser such as IE 11 or Microsoft Edge to see if they provide you better error message than the simple error from Chrome.

Comment: Solution was to open the control panel -> programs, find IIS and select Repair.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution anywhere online that would help me out until I removed the bindings that I was trying to access via the IIS site bindings in IIS manager - see below :
[image]

This was the only binding I kept - I removed the other bindings which were pointed at the ports that I needed.